# Linker error - linking two "application" type projects in order to use Google Test

Tags: c++, linker-errors, googletest

I am trying to test a function with Google Test.

It seems that everything is set up correctly, and it builds and executes fine without gtest... (There is a bit of complexity in the code, so I cannot list all the source files here, but without adding gtest, the files are linking properly, and running as they should).

It is an application type project. It has a number of library dependencies... irrelevant.

The test project is added as a separate project to the solution. It has the tested project as a dependency. The .h file of the test project only points to the gtest... The .cpp (not main, which is the standard InitGoogleTest main) adds its own header file, the header file of the tested project, and has the test shown below.

There is a TestedProject.lib created automatically, when the project builds, even though it is an application. I have added TestedProject.lib as a library dependency to the TestProject (in Link).

```
Class x
{
public:
  x(){}    // I didn't really need this, I only added the class so I have access to 
  ~x(){};  // non-class methods with gtest - but it still doesn't work
  bool myFunction(std::string a, double b, bool c);  
};
```

implementation:

```
bool x::myFunction(std::string a, double b, bool c)
{
  // implementation
  return false;
}

somewhere_else
{
  x x_instance;
  y = x_instance.myFunction("a", 1, false);   // works, all builds, executes, life is great
}
```

Add unit test:

```
class TheTest : public ::testing::Test
{
protected:
    x x_instance;
};

TEST_F(TheTest, Fail)
{
    EXPECT_FALSE(x_instance.myFunction("a", 1, false));     
}
```

Doesn't build. Link error (modified, like the sample code above, with simplified names, I hope I didn't mess up content)

```
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
"public: bool __thiscall x::myFunction(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,double,bool)" 
(?myFunction@x@@QAE_NV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@00000NNNN_N1@Z) 
referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall TheTest_Fail_Test::TestBody(void)" 
(?TestBody@TheTest_Fail_Test@@EAEXXZ)   C:\path\file.obj
```

I have done this before - solved link errors - wrote a couple of tests with Google test - but I can't see anything missing.

As a test, I wrote a little

int test(){return 4;}
in the header file, in the class declaration...

and then, replaced the test with
EXPECT_EQ(x.test(), 4);

It worked. Great. But that would mean to have all the tested code in a single file, a cpp or something... which is simply unreasonable. There are a few files in this Application project.

How can I fix this issue ? How can I make Google Test link and test with a class with a header and an implementation file ? When that header/implementation is in a different project, of "Application" type ?

The only similar issue I have found, so far: [C++ linking issue on Visual Studio 2008 when crosslinking different projects on same solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507595/c-linking-issue-on-visual-studio-2008-when-crosslinking-different-projects-on)

Please, help me find a solution.

Comment: Normally you'd have a library (or some libraries) which make up the bulk of your own code, and an exe/application with just a `main` function which links your lib(s).  This way you can have another project with a different `main` and a pile of testing code (in multiple files if you need) which *also* links your lib(s).  You shouldn't expect to be able to link 2 applications with 2 `main`s.

Comment: Thank you. That is how I ended up implementing it, as soon as I finished asking the question, really - which is when I found the link I added, link which helped me figure it out. I had to create a separate project, and extract only a tiny main() to place into it. I did expect to be able to link 2 applications with main()... and it took me a long time to figure out that I couldn't. I'm sure there's a "link error manual" somewhere, or "what can be tested manual", or "the things other people have tried and failed, so try not to make the same mistake" manual... I'd like to read it.

Comment: Yeah - me too!  Compiler errors are usually much easier to solve than linker ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'll have an answer:

I have 2 solutions to my question:

1) Break up the application project in 2 projects, one will become a library, with most of the code; the other will be an application, containing a tiny main() that calls the entry point of the real code (like a parameter parsing method or something).

Then, I can add a unit testing project - to test the lib.

2) Don't break up the project. Add a gtest project, don't create any dependencies. Add the files to test into the gtest project. The gtest project will be a separate executable... with all it needs to be happy. (Advantage: no dependencies for testing)

I prefer the first version.

Answer (score 10):

There is a another solution, which I prefer because it means you can avoid to change your main project:

Add a "post build action" to the main project in order to create a static library for the exact same source files.
Then you can simply add this dependency to you gtest project.

Each time you'll compile your main project it will build the application AND the static library.

This way you don't have to create a third project and keep configurations synchronized.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Specifically the setting should be: Open the main project property, select Build Event->Post-Build Event tab. Use command *lib /NOLOGO /OUT:"$(TargetPath).lib" "$(ProjectDir)\$(Configuration)\*.obj"* so that this will generate a $(ProjectName).exe.lib file together with the .exe file and it is good for static link to unit test project.

Comment: This answer should be accepted as the best answer. @yc2986 's comment also helps. But for my case, I needed to slightly modify suggested command: _lib /NOLOGO /OUT:"$(TargetPath).lib" "$(ProjectDir)obj\$(Configuration)\$(PlatformTarget)\*.obj"_

Comment: 1/3 There's a problem with commands in 2 first comments: it makes assumptions about structure of the folders in the solution and doesn't work on default Visual Studio folder structure on Win32 and x64 platforms.

Comment: 2/3 Visual Studio puts .obj files into the Intermediate Folder, which you can find and set in Project Properties > Configuration Properties > General > Intermediate Directory: https://i.imgur.com/vui47dU.png . Which on Win32 platform is set to `$(Configuration)\` which gets validated to `$(ProjectDir)$(Configuration)\`. But on x64 platform the Intermediate Directory is set to `$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\` which gets validated to `$(ProjectDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\`.

Comment: 3/3 The proper command to build the .lib file on both platforms all the time is: `lib /NOLOGO /OUT:"$(TargetPath).lib" "$(ProjectDir)$(IntDir)*.obj"`. Use the `$(IntDir)`.

Comment: 1/2 Also lmao C++ is so cringe. > Start reading Test Driven Development by Example written by Kent Beck. > Have no previous knowledge of neither Python and Java nor of IntelliJ IDEs. Download IntelliJ IDEA, setup testing framework with quirks in few hours because of poor articles(https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/testing.html#create-test-resources-root). > Follow first chapter in the book with no problems. > Download and setup IntelliJ PyCharm > Setup testing framework in minutes. > Follow second and third chapters in the book until the very last page with no problems.

Comment: 2/2 > Switch to C# to try it on your own project. Setup testing framework in seconds. Develop using TDD. > Time for C++ project. Create solution with a Win32 console application. Spend 2 days googling Google Test, compiler and linker errors because everything is cringe and refuses to work. In the end still can't setup the way you want it: place testing classes next to the tested classes in the same project. > C++

Comment: May i suggest you to also precise in your answer that the `main` object should be _removed_ from the static library to avoid a linker override on `libgtest_main` ? See @Radek [useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45649761/3641635) on that point.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution for this.

Just create a new project for Google Test Framework. 
(of course, under your existing application solution).

And then, after you make sure all your Google Test Framework setup correctly. 
(you can test it under the newly created solution)

Manually include the code your want test (use Add -> Existing Item) from your main project, and then you can test your code without generate additional lib.

The good part of this is that when you test some application which requires DLL from windows, it requires the application uses Multi-threaded Debug DLL. 
(in your Project property settings, go to C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library see what you got)

And Google Test Framework uses a very different RunTime Library (Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)).

At the stage of linking, the compiler will cry that it has some difficulty links the generated lib from your application with Multi-Thread DLL and the google framework's lib (which is Multi-threaded).

In this way, you can avoid the dependency problem of both project. (one for /Mtd and one for /Md)

Comment: Your solution is identical to what I posted 5 years ago as the second option.

Comment: doesn't hurt to have this as a longer explanation